# Android: ComposerActivity error when user is not logged in native Twitter app when sharing a message using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, android-sharing

First of all I have to say that all works fine when I am logged in in my native Twitter application. I have the problem when I am logged out from my native app.

```
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my message");
    tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");

    PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    boolean hasTwitterApp = false;
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
        if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity")) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            tweetIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            tweetIntent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
            hasTwitterApp = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hasTwitterApp) {
        startActivity(tweetIntent);
    }
```

The error which I am getting in the console:

```
12-16 18:18:22.794 14130-14130/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter.android/com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.twitter.android.composer.bd.a()' on a null object reference

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.twitter.android.composer.bd.a()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be that the mentioned activity may not exists or missing.

Try this - change twitter package name from

```
"com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity"
```

to

```
"com.twitter.android"
```

and use **intent.setPackage** directly to open twitter.

Try below code to share text in twitter.

```
Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my message");
tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
tweetIntent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
startActivity(tweetIntent);
```

Happy Coding..!!